# cakephp upload plugin - define what directory to save files in

Tags: php, image, cakephp, upload

I'm using cakephp-upload [plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) of jose gonzalez to upload images to our app. By default, they're being saved in a directory like this: `webroot/files/user/photo/{user_id}` which is fine, except for when we want to display such images using `$this->Html->image()` which searches for images in the webroot/img directory.

I have already tried to display the images with

```
echo $this->Html->image('../files/user/photo/' .
        $user['User']['photo_dir'] . '/' .
        $user['User']['photo']);
```

which works but I was wondering if there's some way to tell this plugin to save into the img directory? The documentation doesn't mention any of that.

And also, is there any way to tell the `$this->Form->input('User.photo', array('type' => 'file'));` to accept only image files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can see in this [file](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/blob/master/Model/Behavior/UploadBehavior.php), `path` is set like:

```
public $defaults = array(
    'rootDir' => null,
    'pathMethod' => 'primaryKey',
    'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}files{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}',
...
```

you could change it to make:

```
'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}'
```

and for your second question, you could use `accept` attribute, like:

```
$this->Form->input('User.photo', 
    array(
        'type' => 'file', 
        'options' => array('accept' => 'image/*')
    )
);
```